# Create an object from a string using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string that looks like this:

```
YA...Y..............
```

I need to create an object out of this. I was going to try to create an array from the string (but can't see how) if there was a way of doing a split on character index. 
Then I was going to loop through that array and create an object.

I had a solution a bit like this:

```
// Creat an array
var array = [];

// Get our string length
var len = profileString.length - 1;

// Loop through our lengths
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {

    // Get our current character
    var char = profileString[i];

    // Push our character into our array
    array.push(char);
}

// Create our object
var obj = {};

// Loop through our array
array.forEach(function (item, index) {

    // Add our item to our object
    obj['item' + index] = item;
});

// Return our object
return obj;
```

I need to know if there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: how should the object look like? what have you tried?

Comment: It can look like anything as long as it has unique property names

Comment: i see no property names.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense at all...

Comment: I have tried getting the string length, creating a for loop and creating an array manually by pushing the current string into an array, then looping through the array and adding the values to an object with property names like **item1** and so on

Comment: and each letter is supposed to be the content of that object?! like `{item1: 'Y', item2: 'A', item3: '.'}` and so on? You'll have to make yourself clearer on what you want to achieve!

Comment: Yes, that is precisely it. I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

```js
console.log(Object.create([...'YA...Y..............']));
```

ES5

```js
console.log(Object.create('YA...Y..............'.split('')));
```

Comment: Oooo I like that, I shall give it a go and see if it works

Comment: I get an error: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: YI.Y................

Comment: you could try the version with split.

Comment: Worked perfectly, nice job